# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)

Tags: java, excel, poi-hssf, xssf

i want to read the  2010 excel file in java using apache poi api ... but it gives me an error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)
i am using xssf 
but if i want to get the data from old format of the excel then it works fine by sing HSSF ..
i dont know what is going with XSSF..here is my code ..plz help me in it.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 * This java program is used to read the data from a Excel file and display them
 * on the console output.
 * 
 * @author dhanago
 */
public class xssff {

    /** Creates a new instance of POIExcelReader */
    public xssff() {
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to display the Excel content to command line.
     * 
     * @param xlsPath
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void displayFromExcel(String xlsPath) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(xlsPath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found in the specified path.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(1);
        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();

            // display row number in the console.
            System.out.println();

            // once get a row its time to iterate through cells.
            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();

            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                /*
                 * Now we will get the cell type and display the values
                 * accordingly.
                 */
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: {

                    // cell type numeric.
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t");

                    break;
                }

                case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: {

                    // cell type string.
                    XSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell
                            .getRichStringCellValue();

                    System.out.print(richTextString.getString() + "\t\t\t");

                    break;
                }

                default: {

                    // types other than String and Numeric.
                    System.out.println("Type not supported.");

                    break;
                }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * The main executable method to test displayFromExcel method.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        xssff poiExample = new xssff();
        String xlsPath = "c://temp//data.xlsx";

        poiExample.displayFromExcel(xlsPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(1);` must be `XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);`. Also, check that your Excel book has more than 1 sheet.

Comment: still it didnt work with XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0)  and my excel book has only 1 sheet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I've found your problem, you're creating a new book with no sheets

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(1);  //error here, the workBook book has NO sheets!
```

You should create the book based in the InputStream

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new PushbackInputStream(inputStream));
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(1);
```

Or even easier, just pass the file name to create the book:

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsPath);
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = createSheet(workbook, "Sheet 1", false);
XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
```

and that function is:

```
    private static XSSFSheet createSheet(XSSFWorkbook wb, String prefix, boolean isHidden) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        String sName = wb.getSheetName(i);
        if (sName.startsWith(prefix))
            count++;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        sheet = wb.createSheet(prefix + count);
    } else
        sheet = wb.createSheet(prefix);

    if (isHidden)
        wb.setSheetHidden(wb.getNumberOfSheets() - 1, XSSFWorkbook.SHEET_STATE_VERY_HIDDEN);

    return sheet;
}
```